# How to keep Listview Inside the Sliding Drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, slidingdrawer

I have implemented the Sliding Drawer with fixed height which is come from Top to Bottom inside the Drawer 
 I have list view as the content and it's working perfectly but the problem is when my list is getting an increase based on User's selections it does not slide.
 So basically my listview is not scrolled and its locked.
Please find the below attached xml.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_slider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:animateOnClick="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:content="@+id/ll_sliding_content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:visibility="visible">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_sliding_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_nofilter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Active Filter Selected"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_active_filters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff">

            </ListView>


        </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to below link..
http://kalisandroid.blogspot.in/2014/12/custom-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: No,This is the another concept..
My Drawer is from top to bottom@JaiminSarvan

Comment: Use the this Concept
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/slidingdrawer
I think solve the your issue.

Comment: @JaiminSarvan i have the fixed height of sliding Drawer and it's cut the content of listview from the drawer after list has increase the size.